# ABP Framework can't acces virtual files in Deploy

Tags: abp

I'm working with the ABP Framework and I'm implementing my own mail templates.

The project was made using the abp project template. I created the template in my Application module: `Acme.Bookstore.Application/Assets/Templates/MyEmailTemplate.tpl`. I edited the properties of the file to be embedded.

Then I made an instance of the template definition provider as follows:

```
public class MyEmailTemplateDefinitionProvider : TemplateDefinitionProvider
{
    public override void Define(ITemplateDefinitionContext context)
    {
        context.Add(
            new TemplateDefinition(
                MyEmailTemplates.MyEmailTemplate,
                displayName: LocalizableString.Create<AccountResource>($"TextTemplate:{MyEmailTemplates.MyEmailTemplate}"),
                layout: StandardEmailTemplates.Layout,
                localizationResource: typeof(AccountResource)
            ).WithVirtualFilePath($"Assets/Templates/MyEmailTemplate.tpl", true)
        );
    }
}
```

Then I added the following lines to my `BookstoreApplicationModule.cs`

```
Configure<AbpVirtualFileSystemOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.FileSets.AddEmbedded<BookstoreApplicationModule>("Acme.Bookstore");
        });
```

I did all this following this documentation: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.3/Virtual-File-System

**When debugging locally all works well**, but when I deploy the project it can't access the template file. The error is as follows:
`Volo.Abp.AbpException: Could not find a file/folder at the location: Assets/Templates/MyEmailTemplate.tpl`

I already tried adding the `AddEbedded` call in the `HttpApi.Host` module but got the same result. I don't know what I'm missing.

For the record, I'm deploying in an Ubuntu server, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the embedded files weren't being added to the VirtualFileSystem. It worked in develpment because the framework calls:

```
if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            Configure<AbpVirtualFileSystemOptions>(options =>
            {
                ... Some code ...

                options.FileSets.ReplaceEmbeddedByPhysical<BookstoreApplicationModule>(
                    Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,
                        $"..{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}Acme.Bookstore.Application"));
            });
        }
```

So the problem didn't arise until I did a `dotnet publish`.

I could not figure out why it wasn't working on the `Application` module but moving the files to the `Domain.Shared` module fixed it.

I guess that there is some package or setting missing on the other module but this solution is enough for me.